# Interactive notification windows 10 using python

Tags: python, tkinter, notifications, windows-10

I wanted to know if it was possible to show notification with windows 10, that does a specific action when pressed. I know about `plyer` and `win10toast` but in both of those module I don't see a way to configure it to work with clicks. I wanted it so that when i press it, a link will be opened or some function will be run, to work with `tkinter`. Questions here on SO about this are either unanswered or incompatible now. Do you guys have any idea?

**Snippet 1:**

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier

noti = ToastNotifier()
noti.show_toast('Random','Hello World',icon_path='ico.ico',duration=60)
```

Also, despite giving `duration=60` it either way closes automatically after approx. 5 seconds.

**Snippet 2:**

```
from plyer.utils import platform
from plyer import notification

notification.notify(
    title='Here is the title',
    message='Here is the message',
    app_name='Here is the application name',
    app_icon='path/to/the/icon.' + ('ico' if platform == 'win' else 'png')
)
```

After some research i found `win10toast` works with `win32gui`, and some configuration with it could make it work. But i'm not sure what.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `callback_on_click` method to perform a callback on clicking the notification.

As mentioned in this thread [callback_on_click installation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63255660/12870513) you would need to install
`pip install -e git+https://github.com/Charnelx/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications.git#egg=win10toast` as `callback_on_click` is not yet merged with `wintoast`.

You will get an error but your new version of `toastNotifier` will be copied with the existing one.

You would have to import `from src.win10toast.win10toast import ToastNotifier` instead of
`from win10toast import ToastNotifier` inorder to access the `callback_on_click` method.

Please check the snippet.

```
from src.win10toast.win10toast import ToastNotifier
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser

top = tk.Tk()
top.geometry('50x50')
top.title('shop')

url = 'http://www.google.com'

def notify():
   noti.show_toast('Random','Hello World',duration=60, threaded=True,callback_on_click=action) 

def action():
    webbrowser.open_new(url)
    print("Done")
    
noti = ToastNotifier() 
btn = Button(top, text= "Enter", command=notify)
btn.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

NOTE- Make sure you use `threaded=True` in `show_toast()` so that the rest of your program will be allowed to execute while the toast is still active. Else your gui would freeze.

Comment: Just figured it out, instead i just copy pasted the file from github onto the official library.

Comment: Could you actually, help me out by replying to this comment

Comment: @CoolCloud Its good you found another workaround. Make sure that it doesn't interrupts other functionalities.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, because i was testing out a program that needed notification from stack, you can delete it now

Comment: The answer you gave? Yes its fine :D

Comment: @CoolCloud Not about answer. i mean the notification from stackoverflow part

Comment: @Karthik in my case action from callback_on_click function opens new tab in browser during script execution - not on click, but when I use lambda function as an argument for callback_on_click then script works fine.